# Mean stack 2dsphere radius search

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, 2dsphere

I am new to mean stack (and programming in general) but have a simple app up and running.

My model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var RestaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  street: String,
  zip: Boolean,
  city: String,
  country: String,
  location: {
    coordinates: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}
  },
  kitchen: String,
  rating: Number
});

RestaurantSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

export default mongoose.model('Restaurant', RestaurantSchema);
```

I seed my database with:

```
Restaurant.find({}).removeAsync()
  .then(() => {
    Restaurant.create({
      name: 'Kaspers restaurant',
      street: 'Nørrebrogade 1',
      zip: '2200',
      city: 'Copenhagen',
      country: 'Denmark',
      location: ['12.548057','55.7034'],
      kitchen: 'Italian',
      rating: '4.5'
    }, {
      name: 'Kristinas restaurant',
      street: 'Østerbrogade 2',
      zip: '2200',
      city: 'Copenhagen',
      country: 'Denmark',
      location: ['12.541565', '55.689206'],
      kitchen: 'Thai',
      rating: '5'
    }, {
      name: 'Noma',
      street: 'Strandgade 93',
      zip: '1401',
      city: 'Copenhagen',
      country: 'Denmark',
      location: ['12.59620', '55.677933'],
      kitchen: 'Nordisk',
      rating: '6'
    });
  });
```

My controller extracts the users location and list restaurants via:

```
angular.module('venueApp')
  .controller('RestaurantsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
      $http.get('/api/restaurants')
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.restaurants = data;
            console.log($scope.restaurants);
          })
          .error(function(err) {
            console.log('Error! Something went wrong');
          });

      $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.lat = lat;
          $scope.lng = lng;
        });
      });




  });
```

And my view shows the users location, takes maximum input and lists restaurants via:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<div>
    This is your location:
    <input type="text" class="disabled" placeholder="{{lat}}">
    <input type="text" class="disabled" placeholder="{{lng}}">
    <br>
    How far do you want to search:
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="distance">Max. Distance (miles)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distance" placeholder="500" ng-model="formData.distance">
    </div>


</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>By</th>
        <th>Køkken</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Longtitude</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants">
                <td>{{restaurant.name}}</td>
                <td>{{restaurant.city}}</td>
                <td>{{restaurant.kitchen}}</td>
                <td>{{restaurant.location.coordinates[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{restaurant.location.coordinates[1]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have used yeoman angular-fullstack generator. In my html view I extract the users current location "lat" and "lng" and would like to then search through the database of restaurants that are within a max distance from the user.

How do I do this in this scaffold?
I have tried to get these examples/tutorials to work but to no avail :(

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-ii
- https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#searching-for-restaurants

Comment: The field as defined in your schema should be `"location": { "coordinates": [ 12.541565,  55.689206 ] }` or change your schema to `"location": [Numeric]`. Also note you should be using numeric values and not strings, even though mongoose will cast the correct type for you. Then this is a simple matter of a [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) query or [`$nearShere`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) where [`$maxDistance`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/) specifies the radius.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Changed the schema to "location": { "coordinates": [coord1, coord2]. 

Could you help me with exactly what to add to my controller?

Comment: My point was your "seed" data is structured incorrectly for this. The links in the comments to the documentation should have sufficient examples of the required query operator usage.